# Polynomials: zeros, multiplicity, and whether the graph crosses through the $x$ axis there

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Here are the choices:

A) -3, multiplicity 1, touches x-axis; 3, multiplicity 3

B) -3, multiplicity 1, crosses x-axis; 3, multiplicity 3, crosses x-axis

C) 3, multiplicity 1, crosses x-axis; -3, multiplicity 3, crosses x-axis

D) 3, multiplicity 1, touches x-axis; -3, multiplicity 3

The function is $$f(x) = 5(x+3)(x-3)^3.$$

Please help me figure this out. And if possible can you provide the steps and explanation :)

Comment: Missing a power on the second factor.

Comment: That was the way it was given to me on the review sheet :/ @JohnD

Comment: Looks like a typo.

Comment: maybe this? f(x) = 5(x+3)(x-3)^3 @JohnD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: In $(x-a)^m(x-b)^n$, $x=a$ is a zero of multiplicity $m$ and $x=b$ is a zero of multiplicity $n$.

When the multiplicity of a root is even, the graph does NOT cross through the $x$ axis at that point, but it does when the multiplicty is odd.

Comment: So how would I know if it crosses or touches? So the answer would be -3, multiplicity 1; 3, multiplicity 3

Comment: oops fixed the typo... left out word "not"

Comment: Thank you so much :) you honestly helped me a lot